# PBKDF2 key generation using pkcs11interop, c#, windows visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, pkcs#11, pkcs11interop

How to make attribute template for PBKDF2 key generation in pkcs11interop.

Below is my trial code :

```
byte[] randomSalt = session.GenerateRandom(20);

objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKZ.CKZ_SALT_SPECIFIED));    
objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_VALUE, randomSalt));    
objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, 1000));
objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, 0x00000004));    
objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_VALUE, new byte[] { }));    
objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_VALUE, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("password")));
```

`Mechanism mechanism = new Mechanism(CKM.CKM_PKCS5_PBKD2);
objectHandle objectHandle = session.GenerateKey(mechanism, objectAttributes);`

With this I am getting **CKR_MECHANISM_INVALID** exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you are trying to provide parameters to `CKM_PKCS5_PBKD2` mechanism via list of `ObjectAttribute`-s instead of `CkPkcs5Pbkd2Params` class instance. For more information take a look at chapter 12.26.9 of [PKCS#11 v2.20 specification](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS/tree/master/v2.20).

The second problem is that your unmanaged PKCS#11 library most likely does not support `CKM_PKCS5_PBKD2` mechanism at all because by returning `CKR_MECHANISM_INVALID` error your unmanaged PKCS#11 library is telling you that *"An invalid mechanism was specified to the cryptographic operation"*. You can use `GetMechanismInfo()` method to check whether the mechanism is supported:

```
if (!slot.GetMechanismList().Contains(CKM.CKM_PKCS5_PBKD2))
    throw new Exception("Unmanaged PKCS#11 library does not support CKM_PKCS5_PBKD2 mechanism");
```

Comment: `byte[] randomSalt = session.GenerateRandom(20);  

CkPkcs5Pbkd2Params2 mechParams = new CkPkcs5Pbkd2Params2(CKZ.CKZ_SALT_SPECIFIED, randomSalt, 1000, 0x00000001, null, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("password"));
`

I have also tried this, but got stuck at how to use this with 
`Mechanism mechanism = new Mechanism(CKM.CKM_PKCS5_PBKD2);  

ObjectHandle objectHandle = session.GenerateKey(mechanism, mechParams );
`
How to use mechanism parameters with generate key function, as it always requires attribute template.

Comment: @unique12313123231 mechanism parameters need to be provided in constructor of `Mechanism` object this way `Mechanism mechanism = new Mechanism(CKM.CKM_PKCS5_PBKD2, mechParams )`. Attribute template specifies attributes of the newly generated key. For more information take a look at chapter 10 and chapter 11.14 of PKCS#11 v2.20 spec.